# instant Search functionality to listview using edittext in xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, adapter

I am trying to implement instant search functionality using edittext.I have just binded the json array response to listview and added edittext at top of listview and trying to filter or search data in listview as user starts to type in edittext below code is used.Please help me. Any kind of suggestion,guidence and help is appreciated.

MainActivity.cs

```
  SetContentView(Resource.Layout.HomeScreen);
                tableItems = new List<TableItem>();

                var client = new RestClient("http://azurewebsites.net/");
                var request = new RestRequest("Service/regionSearch", Method.POST);
                request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
                tableItems = client.Execute<List<TableItem>>(request).Data;

                listView.Adapter = new HomeScreenAdapter(this, tableItems);
                 region = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.viewtext);
     area= FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.viewtext2);
                _filterText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.search);
                listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);
 _filterText.TextChanged += (object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e) => {
                // filter on text changed
                var searchTerm = _filterText.Text;
};    


        listView.ItemClick += OnListItemClick;
    }

    protected void OnListItemClick(object sender, Android.Widget.AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var listView = sender as ListView;
         var t = tableItems[e.Position];
    //   var clickedTableItem = listView.Adapter[e.Position];
        Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText(this, clickedTableItem.DDLValue, Android.Widget.ToastLength.Short).Show();

    }
```

HomeScreenAdapter.cs

```
public class HomeScreenAdapter : BaseAdapter<TableItem> {
    List<TableItem> items;
    Activity context;
    public HomeScreenAdapter(Activity context, List<TableItem> items)
        : base()
    {

            this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }
    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override TableItem this[int position]
    {
        get { return items[position]; }
    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get { return items.Count; }
    }
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
             var item = items[position];

          //  TableItem item = items[position];


            View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomView, null);
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text1).Text = item.DDLValue;
       view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text2).Text = item.areaMsg;
          return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're pretty close. The last step is to use the `searchTerm` to filter out the results in `tableItems`. The easiest way to do this is to simply create a new `HomeScreenAdapter` with the filtered list, and set that as the `ListView.Adapter`. Check out this example code that implements: getting the search text, filtering all of your TableItem instances, and then giving the ListView a new Adapter.

```
 _filterText.TextChanged += (object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e) => {
            // filter on text changed
            var searchTerm = _filterText.Text;
            var updatedTableItems = tableItems.Where(
                // TODO Fill in your search, for example:
                tableItem => tableItem.Msg.Contains(searchTerm) ||
                             tableItem.DDLValue.Contains(searchTerm)
            ).ToList();
            var filteredResultsAdapter = new HomeScreenAdapter(this, updatedTableItems);
            listView.Adapter = filteredResultsAdapter;
 };
```

Notice the TODO inside of the Where clause. I have no idea how you want to search on your `TableItem` but once you write your Where clause, this should do what you want.

It looks like your `TableItem` class is something like this (for reference):

```
public class TableItem {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string DDLValue {get; set;}
    public string Msg {get; set;}
    public int Status {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Hi,here i want to search for letter or text/word that is present in listview as user enters.It has to search for all the two text fields that are in listview. I need some more help to do list.

Comment: i want to search for this elements containing typed text in editfield.Please help me i am new to c# and Xamarin    public class TableItem {
      
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string DDLValue { get; set; }
        public string Msg { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }

Comment: @dafodil I have written an implementing that will check if either `DDLValue` or `Msg` contain the `searchTerm` as a substring.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: here  on click of particular row not able to retrieve that particular object after searching.How could i do that?

Comment: `var clickedTableItem = listView.Adapter[e.Postion];` I'm assuming that this is in your `OnListItemClick` method where `e` is a `ItemClickEventArgs`. If you need more detail, it is probably best to ask another specific question. Regards.

Comment: Yes sir i had used this protected void OnListItemClick(object sender, Android.Widget.AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) { var listView = sender as ListView; var t = tableItems[e.Position]; // var clickedTableItem = listView.Adapter[e.Position]; Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText(this, clickedTableItem.DDLValue, Android.Widget.ToastLength.Short).Show(); }in my onclick of listitem

Comment: ------ –but it is giving me original listview data object on click.i.e after filtering if i get second row in first of filtered list ,on click i am able to retrieve first object data of listview .If i apply your code of line i get error saying "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type `Ilistadapter'.See my updated code with onclcik

Comment: You should be able to do something like... `var selectedTableItem = e.Parent.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);` to get the correct item. You specifically CANNOT try to use `e.Position` as in index into `tableItems` because that index does not come from `tableItems` - it is from a subset of `tableItems`.

Comment: by using this how to access ddlvaue and msg from selectedTableItem  i am getting particular object correctly on click when debug ,but not able to get ddlvalue or items of object.

Comment: I don't completely understand the question, but I suspect the problem is the type. In my example, `selectedTableItem` will be a very generic type (like `object`) and not `TableItem`. You should be able to cast it like so: `var selectedTableItem = (TableItem) e.Parent.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);` and then you will have all of the properties.

Comment: after making above changes it was showing cannot convert type java.lang.object to tableitem.When i googled about this i found below code   public static class ObjectTypeHelper
{
    public static T Cast<T>(this Java.Lang.Object obj) where T : class
    {
        var propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Instance");
        return propertyInfo == null ? null : propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null) as T;
    }
}  but how to implement this in my code.

Comment: @ Dylan S please help me in this to access particular row after filtering.it giving me casting error.

Comment: @dafodil Try this: `var selectedTableItem = ((HomeScreenAdapter)listView.Adapter) [e.Position];` the problem is that Java native methods in the adapter return Java Lang Object, and you would have to finagle that back into a `TableItem`. The above approach should prevent that problem by accessing the real adapter and using the C# operator to get the item.